# Access document library of different site

Tags: sharepoint-2010, cross-domain

Hi I have a requirement and I dont know how to start with this -

1. There will be multiple different sites which will have a link to
   access the document library of a different site.
2. Each site will have access to their own set of documents only in the 
   document library.
3. There should be some sort of token which will authorize
   the to access the library without providing id and password.

Comment: Please provide more specific information/detail in the question. ex. more about the terminology of sharepoint. etc.. Until then ques is too broad

Comment: Ok .. Let me try.. There is one SharePoint 2010 website Site X, which has a document library.. Now there are three other sites. Site A, Site B, Site C.. Once some users login to Site A , B or C they should be able to get in Site X without any credentials and get access to there own set of documents in the document library.